# android setAdapter and refresh actionbar in jelly bean

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-4.2-jelly-bean

On the fragment lifecycle of android prior to Jelly bean (might be a bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39721) onCreateOptionsMenu would be call after onCreate, with this bug onCreateOptionsMenu is called after onResume. My problem is that i have a refresh action menu item that is set on onCreateOptionsMenu, if i put loadItemsToAdapter in that function, it wont work prior to JB because onCreateView is not yet called. 
Is there a solution where i dont have to put a flag isCalled and put loadItemsToAdapter on both onCreateOptionsMenu and onCreateView?